# Flagging migrations to Programmers.SE?

Tags: discussion, flags, migration

Now that the close/flag reasons have been changed, we can directly flag a question for migration to a different site on the StackExchange network.

However, there's only 5 options, with an important one missing:  [Programmers.SE](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/), the site for software development at a more conceptual level.

Was this an intentional omission?  I often see questions on here that would do better over there, like this one just now:  [Why is AngularJS called a poor fit for GUI editor apps?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17842692/why-is-angularjs-called-a-poor-fit-for-gui-editor-apps)

<sub>(I'd flagged it as "Needs  moderator attention", then explained that Programmers.SE would be a better fit.  *Then* I realized I should ask here.)</sub>

Comment: What's with all the migration questions and proposals today? :) Anyway, yes, that omission was intentional. Too many rejected migrations in the past. We collectively sucked too much at migrating to Programmers SE.

Comment: @Bart Judging by the first sentence, and indeed first word, it seems a new feature has rolled out. Or has become more clear than it was before.

Comment: Did I miss something @J.Steen? Thought that the new close reasons were in place for a while now....

Comment: @Bart Yeah. Me too. >.> Maybe I'm just conspiring in my own head again.

Comment: @Bart Yeah, not a dupe, but would be a good link to include in an answer that explained that the migration path used to exist but was removed... :)

Comment: Your process for requesting migration to Programmers was the correct one.  If it is not listed, then use a custom flag to ask a moderator to move it.

Comment: @J.Steen and Bart: They have, but I'm far more active on SciFi.SE, else I'd've asked this earlier.  Probably just bad wording on my part.

Comment: @Bart Amusing note, a comment on the answer there is asking exactly my question here (sort of, in a joking way)

Comment: @RobertHarvey Can you see if my comment linking to a related post was removed by flags, or automatically? I don't really get why it's gone. Strange side-effect of your duplicate closure?

Comment: @Bart: Yes, it was deleted as a result of the closure.